# Is it appropriate to use a factor variable that was created from a predictor variable in a Cox PH regression?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

This is for R Studio - Survival Analysis w/ "survival" package data and running Cox PH analysis.

I have a basic survival dataset (nafld1) that includes age and bmi. I created a new variable from the existing data bmi. I created a category A,B, or C based on the quantiles of BMI. So when I include these in the coxph formula and get results, is it okay to include them, or are they somehow getting "double counted" in the regression since the formula looks something like

```
~sex+age+bmi+bmi_g1+bmi_g2+bmi_g3
```

Conceptually, it's messing with me because the groups are based on bmi and not technically a completely separate covariate (as opposed to like treatment A or B might be), but more of a refinement of detail from the given data.

Any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if you need further detail.

Comment: It's not mathematically wrong but it's not necessarily the best approach. Can you say more about what your goal is including these quantile variables? I'm voting to close/migrate to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). This is equivalent to modeling log-hazard as the combination of a straight line (`bmi`) and a piecewise-constant function with breakpoints (`bmi_g1 + bmi_g2 + bmi_g3`).

Comment: Yes - The goal was to get more detailed information about how bmi affects the survival of the patients. BMI, globally, may not be statistically significant, but when it's broken down into different groups of low, average, and high it gives a more detailed story and (maybe a bit obviously) we could see that higher bmi has more risk...

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to use a spline or additive model (e.g. `splines::ns(bmi, 6)` where the number represents the degrees of freedom/wiggliness/complexity/number of parameters associated with `bmi`, rather than dichotomizing - see Harrell *Regression Modeling Strategies*

Comment: Thank you. That is a bit above my skill level at the moment. I'm doing this for a final project in an elective course and we have not covered splines or additive models in our class.

Comment: You could drop it in there and see what happens ...